# Vuex two commits in same action does not trigger watch

Tags: vue.js, vuex

When I watch `$store.stateA`, the watch callback function for the following seems to not trigger.

```
stateA: false

muationA(state,val){
 state.stateA = val  
}

actionA({commit},val) {
  commit('mutationA', true)
  commit('mutationB', false) //take this out would trigger the watch callback
}
```

So what is the case here? the entire action callback need to finish before the watch functions are triggered?

Comment: Mutations are synchronous operations, you set the value to `true`, then back to `false` right away, and only then is the thread free to check on the watcher.

Comment: Well, if the watchers are coded utilizing the defineProperty of javascript, the callbacks should be embedded in the setters of those properties and triggered immediately before going to the next line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nit mentioned, both mutations cancel each other since they are done synchronously. Read the "[Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)" section of the doc for more info. In particular (emphasis mine):

> In case you haven’t noticed yet, Vue performs DOM updates asynchronously. Whenever a data change is observed, it will open a queue and buffer all the data changes that happen in the same event loop. **If the same watcher is triggered multiple times, it will be pushed into the queue only once**. This buffered de-duplication is important in avoiding unnecessary calculations and DOM manipulations. Then, in the next event loop “tick”, Vue flushes the queue and performs the actual (already de-duped) work.

Other watcher solutions do work differently and are triggered right away when the value changes (e.g. Backbone.js). Vue does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted once to use a vuex variable as an event transmitter across components and needed to set a boolean variable to `false` and immediately to `true` afterward.  I however saw that the `watch` in the component did not pick it up. The issue as mentioned in the other post is that they cancel each other because they are in the same event loop.

In order to make that work, I just had to separate their event loop by waiting for the `Vue.nextTick()` as follows:

```
// First operation
await Vue.nextTick();
// Second operation
```